# What is the negation of "x is odd and y is even"?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I'm not sure if I find the correct answer to this question.

Using De Morgan's law;

¬(a∧b)=(¬a)∨(¬b)

so it becomes:

X is not odd OR Y is not even

or also we can say,

X is even OR Y is ODD.

Can somebody correct me if I'm wrong OR tell me if I'm right :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are right: for integers $X$ and $Y$ the negation is: $X$ is even or $Y$ is odd.

Answer (score 1):

Well, not odd means even, and not even means odd. Hence, you're absolutely correct.^^